# App registration to access Uber api

Tags: android, registration, uber-api

I have been trying to link Uber api to my app. 
The User registration is successful but when i tried to create an app it says "Before you can create an application, we need to confirm your phone number."

How do i confirm my number to proceed further ?

Any input ?

Comment: I've been having the same issue as well. @Atmaram did you get a solution for this ?

Comment: No, not yet. I ended up using an account from UK to start using the API.

Comment: I got this resolved for me. I went to this link (https://help.uber.com/h/7dfdeaa8-9973-44da-82a7-215ee030cef3) on uber Help page and gave my number. Somebody from their support wrote back and I explained him the problem. He fixed it for me from their backend.

Answer (score 2):

To confirm your mobile number, just text the word `go` to 827-222.

If you don’t get a reply saying that your number was confirmed or the response is "Message blocking is active," your mobile service provider may be blocking you from texting our number. Give your provider a call to see if they will let you text 827-222.

Google Voice users may have to login to http://google.com/voice in order to text the word `go` to 827-222.

Still having trouble confirming your mobile number? We can help you at t.uber.com/support

If after doing this, and you still cannot create an application, please try to logout of the developer portal by visiting:

https://developer.uber.com/apps/logout

There was a caching issue where the developer portal didn't recognize when a mobile number was successfully confirmed.

Comment: I believe the number 827-222 is valid only for US, and not for other countries.

Comment: what to do for INDIA?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this [link](https://help.uber.com/h/7dfdeaa8-9973-44da-82a7-215ee030cef3) on uber Help page and enter your mobile number. Somebody from their support will get back to you over email. Explain the issue to them and they will resolve it for you from their internal tool/backend system. This is how I resolved it for myself.

Comment: I tried the same process. mail from support team suggests my phone number is verified. but while creating app, i get the same error "Before you can create an application, we need to confirm your phone number. Text GO to 827-222. Please see the confirm mobile phone number help page for more information." I will get in touch with their support team and try to resolve the issue. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yes, once you get that email, just reply to that email saying that I need to register for Uber Hackathon challenge, and when I try to do so - it gives me the aforementioned error. And pray that the request is routed to a customer support executive who knows about this problem and its solution :) ATB